# Counting random numbers

Tags: python

Suppose I repeatedly generate random integers from 0-9 until a given number comes out. What I need is a function that counts how many integers are generated until this happens. Please help me with this.

This is what I have tried, I put 1000 becasue it is big enough but I don't think it is correct because my number can come after 1000 iterations.

```
for i in range(1000):
  d = randint()
  if d <> 5:
     cnt = cnt + 1
  if d == 5:
     break
```

Comment: Instead of simulating, you could just sample once from a [geometric distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution) with probability 0.1.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Suppose **5** is the number you are expecting:

```
sum(1 for _ in iter(lambda: randint(0, 9), 5))
```

You can add **1** if you want to include the last number.

**Explanation**:

- `iter(function, val)` returns an iterator that calls `function` until
  `val` is returned.
- `lambda: randint(0, 9)` is function (can be called) that *returns* `randint(0, 9)`.
- `sum(1 for _ in iterator)` calculates the length of an iterator.

Comment: I don't think generator expressions and anonymous functions are really in OP's grasp if he's still struggling with loops.

Comment: what is the meaning of "_"?

Comment: It is just a variable, you can rename it as you want. See my edited answer.

Comment: The second one (the `list()` one) is not so great, because you may be building a very big list before the desired value is encountered, and it may eat a lot of memory.

Comment: @Blender, I think it is good both to have answers like yours but also to expose him to this stuff so that he is pushed to learn more.

Comment: @Hammerite, I added it because it looks simpler but you are right, I have added a note.

Comment: +1 for brevity. But your call to randint should be on (0,9) not (0,10).  Randint includes both endpoints.

Comment: I'd up-vote this if you hadn't put in the alternative because it's such a poor approach...beyond even the potential for the list being very large.

Comment: @martineau well, there were some concerns of the comprehension being too complicated for the OP but I think you are right, I also hate it so I will take it away.

Answer (score 9):

A few things:

- If you want your loop to continue until you stop it, use a `while` loop instead of a `for` loop.
- You should use `!=` as the inequality operator instead of `<>`.

Here's something to get you started:

```
import random

count = 0

while True:
    n = random.randint(0, 9)
    count += 1

    if n == 5:
        break
```

You could also write:

```
import random

count = 1
n = random.randint(0, 9)

while n != 5:
    count += 1
    n = random.randint(0, 9)
```

Converting it into a function is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Your answers (as is the OP's own code) are off by one if they're suppose to count how many random integers were generated.

Comment: `<>` is used in pre-python 3 and replaced by the parser with `!=`.

Comment: @Sp.: Thanks, I never knew that. I thought it was just for pre-2.6.

Answer (score 2):

`itertools.count` is often neater than using a while loop with an explicit counter

```
import random, itertools

for count in itertools.count():
    if random.randint(0, 9) == 5:
        break
```

If you want the count to include the iteration that generates 5, just start the count at 1 using  `itertools.count(1)`

Answer (score 1):

```
from random import randint
count = 0
while randint(0, 9) != 5:
   count += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
from random import randint
# Make sure 'cnt' is outside the loop (otherwise it will be overwritten each iteration)
cnt = 0
# Use a while loop for continuous iteration
while True:
    # Python uses '!=' for "not equal", not '<>'
    if randint(0, 9) != 5:
        # You can use '+=' to increment a variable by an amount
        # It's a lot cleaner than 'cnt = cnt + 1'
        cnt += 1 
    else: 
        break
print cnt
```

or, in function form:

```
from random import randint
def func():
    cnt = 0
    while True: 
        if randint(0, 9) != 5:
            cnt += 1 
        else: 
            break
    return cnt
```